# How can I make links out of my PHP twitter feed output?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using a very simple PHP include to grab [my current twitter status](http://twitter.com/#!/jglovier) and output the content into [my website](http://joelglovier.com/). The trouble though, is that the output doesn't generate links like the actual status does when there are URLs in the status.

What is the best or simplest way to make this happen?

Here's the PHP I'm using to populate the status:

```
<?php  
$response = new SimpleXMLElement('http://twitter.com/users/show/jglovier.xml',NULL,TRUE);  
echo $response->status->text.'';  
?>
```

*EDIT: since I'm only a front-end developer most comfortable with HTML, CSS, and barely JS, I'm looking for the simplest fix here, preferably JS based.

Comment: Since it's just plain text, you'd have to scan the text for 'http://' substrings and wrap some `<a>` tags around them.

Comment: Look at this blog post comment:
http://pixelclouds.com/2010/05/06/getting-your-latest-twitter-status-using-php/comment-page-1/#comment-9455

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [bcherry/twitter-text-js](https://github.com/bcherry/twitter-text-js). It will autolink URLs, @mentions, and #hashtags to the specification that twitter.com uses.

Put twitter-text.js on your server, load it after you load jQuery, and run the snippet below on document ready.

```
$('p.status').each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).html(twttr.txt.autoLink($(element).text()));
});
```

Comment: Having some trouble with this one. I'm a jQ novice. I'm really bad with JS syntax...

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a really easy few lines of code:

```
function twitterify($ret) {
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t\\2", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r\\2", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "@\\1", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "#\\1", $ret);
    return $ret;
}
```

Source: http://www.snipe.net/2009/09/php-twitter-clickable-links

Comment: Looks good, but JS solution is easier for me. I don't do well with PHP syntax beyond barebones basics. Thanks though. Maybe this will come in handy when I get better with PHP down the road!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've already solved this as it's been a while since it was posted, but for users wanting to do something similar, I've found this very useful: http://remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step/

Brings in your tweets (as many or few as you specify), but the best thing is, you write out the template of how the tweet is displayed - so time/tweet/poster or poster/tweet/time etc.

Very cool!

Comment: Although the script you've linked to solves the problem of getting twitter links onto a page, it doesn't at all deal with the problem in my question, which was how to parse a plain text twitter feed generated by PHP and add links to a plain text version.

Comment: Look at the examples. It parses http links as well as @username links. You define what it outputs so you have lots of options to work with.